# Detect HTTPS Proxy in PHP or .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https

I have got `ProxyPass` set up in the apache server config.

PHP seems cant detect the HTTPS.

How do i detect the HTTPS in PHP or redirect if not HTTPS in .htaccess?

Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName domain.co.uk
ServerAlias www.domain.co.uk
ProxyPass / http://external-domain.com/

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
...

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Source: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Answer (score 1):

This will check in PHP if you're on HTTPS.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) { 
}
```

Comment: You're right, I edited accordingly. Checking 443 was correct in this scenario, but not general enough.